# Dota 2 API Question

Tags: web-development, php, api

I've got a project, I'd like to create a Platform for Dota 2. I've done tons of research. However, I don't find what I need.

Basically, I need a Dota 2 API that I can integrate via PHP (Laravel). This platform would have matchmaking capabilities. I tried looking at this: [OpenDota API](https://docs.opendota.com/).

A good example of this would be Epulze.com